# System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: xml, vb.net

In our transportation services website, a user who wishes to request transportation services has the option of requesting a preferred trip type.

The options are:

```
By hourly service,
By Mileage
By flat rate
```

If a user choses By Mileage option, then total mileage is calculated between two locations and this works fine.

If, however, a user choses any option other than By Mileage, then the following exception is raised.

***System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.***

Any ideas what could be causing this or how to resolve it?

The error points to this sub, specifically,

**geocoderXmlDoc.Load(geocoderUri)**

```vb
Private Sub fdistcal(ByVal street As String, ByVal city As String, ByVal state As String)
    Dim geocoderUri As String = String.Format("http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/rest?address={0},{1},{2}", street, city, state)
    Dim geocoderXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    geocoderXmlDoc.Load(geocoderUri)
    Dim nsMgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(geocoderXmlDoc.NameTable)
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#")
    Dim sLong As String = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//geo:long", nsMgr).InnerText
    Dim sLat As String = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//geo:lat", nsMgr).InnerText
    Dim latitude As Double = [Double].Parse(sLat)
    Dim longitude As Double = [Double].Parse(sLong)
    '   Response.Write("Latitude: " + latitude + "<br /> Longitude: " + longitude);
    flatitude = latitude
    flongitude = longitude
End Sub
```

```
<asp:DropdownList ID="tripType" runat="server" class="select " onchange="ShowHideDiv();"> 
    <asp:ListItem value="">--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="FlatRate">Flat Rate</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="hourly">Hourly/Charter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="miles">By Mileage</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropdownList>
```

```
function ShowHideDiv() {
    //Get dropdown selected value
    var SelectedValue = $("#tripType").val();
    // check selected value.
    if (SelectedValue == 'FlatRate') {
        $('#fromCity').fadeIn();
        $('#toCity').fadeIn();
        $('#FromLoc').fadeOut();
        $('#ToLoc').fadeOut();
    }
    elsif (SelectedValue == 'miles') {
        $('#fromCity').fadeOut();
        $('#toCity').fadeOut();
        $('#FromLoc').fadeIn();
        $('#ToLoc').fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the output of your service request? I think you may not be getting an xml format back

Comment: It seems the rest service you are calling has malformed Xml (or possibly is JSON or a 500 error message, etc). Navigate to the URL via a browser and see what it returns?

Comment: Show the content of the `geocoderUri` variable in the two cases.

Comment: Most likely, in the "mileage" case, the service is returning an error message, perhaps in HTML.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.

@StuartLC, nothing is being returned. I am not sure it made it that far.

John, I have just added a bit of code snip since it is a long code.

I suspected the reason could be that when mileage is null, it throws that exception.